# Typescript generics: pass key as function arg, infer another arg as value

Tags: typescript

### What I want

I have an object and a 'consumer' function that takes a key and handler function, then passes the value for that key to the handler.

I want Typescript to infer the correct type for the handler function, given an arbitrary key at runtime.

I want this to use the key as a 'selector' for the correct handler, and have type safety in using that handler. I know I could manually type the argument in the handler given the key, but I want it to be inferred automatically to have proper type safety. For example, to break if I change the key and not the implementation of the handler.

### What I've tried

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMDOAeGA+KBeKAbwCgooBtAaSmSgGsIQB7AM1gF0AuWK94gX2LFQkWIlQBhJkjQBXALYQATlgA0UahAAewCEgAmaeo1axcBABSkoLJkvjIUAeRYxwEbpVXW4AQwMANsrcFgBuvgGyHjyU7ACU+LihTAj63gl4SSn6QiyySADGwAjSUAVKEL66DqiYOBbA4ujcNehY2HEtTXW4JGQVwLJKSFCNjmgCuflFJSPlldVNUjIKymoaUNq6BkYMzGz11mO1XePt6aeS0nKKKjDqlL3WA0MjFrb2TS5ukOp+gcoMrh-vogkoGt1yB9Wt93PFJsQCtdgKNuvgyhUqhBWmgLH0oL5uIQbEwmNwAIzqABGviU3AATFB+N4yFSiVAaQAvbgAZiZ3n4cSESJkKOOKGWN2UBHmWNaktW4PFaCFwiW10VFgA5L4teowhEokCiNYRWgmEEAHQBJgoA2RCCW2xMKAAaig5KFguIQA)

```js
type Things<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
}

type ThingConsumer<T, K extends keyof T> = (
  forThingOfType: K,
  handler: (value: T[K]) => void,
) => void

function createThings<T>(things: Things<T>): Things<T> {
  return things
}

function createThingConsumer<T, K extends keyof T>(
  things: Things<T>,
): ThingConsumer<T, K> {
  return (forThingOfType, handler) => handler(things[forThingOfType])
}

const things = createThings({
  a: { foo: 1, bar: 2 },
  b: { baz: 3 },
})

const thingConsumer= createThingConsumer(things)

thingConsumer('a', (value) => {
  console.log(value.foo + 1) // <-- error: Object may be 'undefined'
})
```

### What doesn't work

It appears that Typescript can't infer the concrete type of `value` correctly as `{ foo: number, bar: number }` from the passed key, `'a'`.

Instead, it infers `value` as a union type of *all possible* values of `things`, i.e.

```
{ foo: number, bar: number } | { baz: number }
```

And then the error message when trying to use `value.foo` is very unexpected. It says that the "Object" may be undefined. If anything, I would have expected it to complain that `foo` might be undefined, given the union type inference, but not that `value` itself may be undefined.

### Is what I'm trying to do possible?

It feels like it ought to be - in particular I really thought that the `T[K]` syntax says 'for a given concrete key `K` of an object, resolve the type of the corresponding value'. But perhaps it's not that powerful and is instead saying 'for *any* key, resolve *any* value'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<K extends keyof T>` should be moved as a property of the returned function rather than the higher order function.

```
type ThingConsumer<T> = <K extends keyof T>(
  forThingOfType: K,
  handler: (value: T[K]) => void,
) => void
```

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMDOAeGA+KBeKAbwCgooBtAaSmSgGsIQB7AM1gF0AuWK94gX2LFQkWIlQBhJkjQBXALYQATllwEM1CAA9gEJABM09Rq1jYAFKSgsmS+MhQB5FjHARulADRW4AQwMANsrc5gBuvgGy7jyU7ACU+LihTAj63gl4SSn6QiyySADGwAjSUAVKEL669qiYOObA4ujcNeiqcS1NdbgkZBXAskpIUI0OaAK5+UUlw+WV1U1SMgrKWJ5Qmjp6hsbMbPVWo7WdY6rpJ5LScooqOERW-YPD5jZ2Tc6ukOt+gcoZuD99EElA0uuRXq0Pm54hNiAUrsARl18GUKlUIK00OZelBfNxCNYmExuABGdYAI18Sm4ACYoPxvGRyfioJSAF7cADM9O8-DiQnhMkRRxQS2uygIc3RrTFKxBIrQ-OEiyucvMAHJfOr1mEIlF-vcyIK0EwggA6AJMFC6yIQM02JhQADUUBJ-L5xCAA